# Extjs with rails form submit problem

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, extjs

I am creating a web application using EXT JS and Rails. I have a controller  **basic controller** that contains the basic template ( master page ), clicking on the menu button would open a tab within tab panel and render some grid or form as required.

how to submit the form that is rendered from some other controller( for e.g : **units controller**) to the basic controller?

Code for Form submit that worked in separate project :

```
var sbtn=Ext.getCmp('btnSave');
sbtn.on('click',function(){
    var frm=Ext.getCmp('myform');

    frm.getForm().submit('/units/new', function() {
        alert('Submitted')
    });
});
```

But when i use the same in my application it goes on to "basic/index" instead of "units/new" ?

Any Suggestion ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my own problem: I did it using JSON and Ajax.Request

```
        var sbtn=Ext.getCmp('btnSave');

                sbtn.on('click',function(){    
             var unitname =  Ext.getCmp('unitname').getValue();
             var description =  Ext.getCmp('description').getValue();
             var post_json = {"data": { "unitname" : unitname, "description" :description }};
                var frm=Ext.getCmp('myform');
                frm.getForm().submit(    
                Ext.Ajax.request({    
                url: '/units',
                method: 'POST',
                jsonData: post_json,
                            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json' , 'Accept' : 'application/json'}

                  }))        
   });
```